# MySQL - Listing all users and grants into one single view

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, report

I am looking for a way to generate a users/permissions report for MySQL. Said report should list all the users, and their grants per schema.

```
[username, schema, privs]
user1, myschema, select, update, ...
...  , ..., ..., ..., ...
```

I've seen multiple threads across the community, most of them were referring to it as a missing functionality of some sort.

The only thing which was somewhat satisfactory for me was using concat:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR \'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\';') FROM mysql.user;
```

The issue with that is the fact that it only returns a list of commands:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR \'user1\'@\'%\';
SHOW GRANTS FOR \'user2\'@\'%\';
SHOW GRANTS FOR \'user..\'@\'%\';
SHOW GRANTS FOR \'userN\'@\'%\';
```

Which later I have to run manually and will result in this (for example):

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'user1\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>'
'GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `%`.* TO \'user1\'@\'%\''
```

Again, the problem is everything is manual.

To sum it all up, I'm looking for a way to:

- Either create a report with all users and their privileges
- Aggregate all the grants into a single table

I need my solution to be "inside the box", staying in the MySQL space, not using anything external (e.g: python script)

I did try using

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES;
```

But it was not sufficient.

Hope I was able to make myself clear,
Cheers